# Cannot install due to screen size

Tags: system-installation, display, high-dpi

Is there a way to acces terminal in the installer so I can change the desktop interface. The screensize is too big and I can not acces the menu's or buttons.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to tty1? If it works you should be able to get back to the GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. After quite some fiddling, I qas able to quit the installer, and the screen actually popped into the correct resolution. I simply clicked the installer (last icon in the dock) to restart the installation wizard. Not sure if this would work for everyone, though...

Answer (score 2):

Hit the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> that will open your applications menu. Once it is open, you can type in the command you need (`pantheon-terminal`, or `switchboard`).

Answer (score 0):

If you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> when you get to screens that you can't navigate, a hand will appear and you can move the panel around so that you can see the [Next] or [Continue] buttons and press them.